# Rotating text with imagestring()

Tags: php

I am working on a small project at the moment. For this project, I need a photo with text in it (to make it harder for bots to figure out the text).

I am following the advice of [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/248726/214772) answer, but [`imagettftext`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagettftext.php) uses true type fonts, which is not possible in my case.
Therefore I searched for an alternative and found [`imagestring`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagestring.php).

So my approach to the problem looks like this:

```php
<?php
    function randExer() {
        //Creating random (simple) math problem
        $arr = array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten");
        $item1 = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
        $item2 = $arr[array_rand($arr)];
        $random = $item1 . " + " . $item2;

        //Saving created math problem for later
        file_put_contents("exercise.txt", $random);

        //Creates a black picture with width=200 and height = 50
        $img = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 50);

        //uses RGB-values to create a useable color
        $white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);

        //Adds white-colored text
        $var = imagestring($img, 5, 18, 18, $random . " = ?", $white);

        //Save image
        imagejpeg($img, "exercise.png", -1);    
    };
?>
```

This is working and the result looks like this:

[image: example]

**The problem**

Is there a way to rotate the text with a certain angle?

Comment: is         $rotate = imagerotate($img, 10, 0); 
        imagejpeg($rotate); what u want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php imagerotate
e.g.

```
    ...
    //Adds white-colored text
    $var = imagestring($img, 5, 18, 18, $random . " = ?", $white);
    $rotate = imagerotate($img, 10, 0);
    //Save image
    imagejpeg($rotate, "exercise.png", -1);   
    ...
```

adjust the second param for an angle